# WPF throw exception from worker thread but continue

Tags: wpf

I have a scenario where a worker thread performs a task that looks like

```
try
{    
    for()
    {
        functionA();
        functionB(); 
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Message");    
}
```

I'm basically re-throwing the exception so that when the worker completes, the UI thread will receive the exception.
Now, if an exception occurs in `functionA` I'd like to throw the exception but continue the loop and not stop. How can I achieve this?

edit: If it isn't clear, this is so that the UI can be notified that an exception has occurred but not stop the worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List<Exception> errorsLog = new List<Exception>();

for()
{
    try
    {
       functionA();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
       errorsLog.Add(e);
    }

    try
    {
       functionB();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
       errorsLog.Add(e);
    }
}

if (errorsLog.Count > 0) {
   throw new AggregateException(errorsLog);
}
```

Where `AggregateException` is your custom exception that contains a list of other exceptions.

Comment: But `functionB` is critical. I have to exit if `functionB` throws an exception. Also, the UI has to be notified immediately that an error has occurred in functionA, not after all of them finish

Comment: In this case, instead of adding exceptions to the list, just use dispatcher to re-throw them in the UI thread: Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => throw MyAsyncException(e))).

Comment: The worker thread is operating on another project. Application.Current.Dispatcher doesnt make sense in the context :(

Comment: Then you should create something like IExeptionReportingService. This inteface will be located in some common assembly and the implementation will be in the UI assembly that knows about Application.Current.Dispatcher.